# How to join arrows within xymatrix?

Tags: diagrams, xy-pic

I use `xymatrix` (`\usepackage[all]{xy}`) in order to create the following picture:

```
\[
  \xymatrix{A \ar@{-}[d] & B \\ \ar[r] & C} 
\]
```

[image]

Is there any possibility to join the lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{
  A \ar `d[dr] [dr] & B \\
                    & C
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A sharper turn can be obtained by

```
\xymatrix{
  A \ar `d/2pt[dr] [dr] & B \\
                        & C
}
```

[image]

Comment: Aw. I just spent the last 15 minutes figuring this out! `xypic` is not the easiest of packages to fathom.

Comment: The part on bending arrows is not very well documented.

Comment: sorry, I have already accepted the previous answer. But this is exactly what I was looking for. Many Many thanks!

Comment: I have to admit, I came across the same basic code you give above but it was trial and error, and rather surprising when I worked it out. Excellent to have it here then!

Comment: @Marco; This is what you actually asked for in the question. Whether you use this or TikZ, this is the correct answer, so I won't hold it against you if you accept this one now. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about `xypic` I'm afraid, but I have an alternative that works well with TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em, ampersand replacement=\&] {%
A \& B \\
  \& C \\
};
\draw[->,rounded corners=1mm] (M-1-1) |- (M-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For more information on TikZ matrices, see section 17 of the [PGF/TikZ manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf).